# USB Drive that can disconnect itself

Tags: linux, windows, macos, usb, connection-sharing

This is just an idea I'm trying to do, but I don't know where to start.
Imagine having a USB Drive that you can connect it to selected PCs. If the USB drive ever get connected to any other device or PC, it will disconnect.
I don't want to use encryption because what if I wanted to do this to a MP3 player. so my only idea that comes to my mind is the auto run file that runes once the USB is connected and look for a file on the connected PC or device, if doesn't find it then it disconnect, if it does then it stay connected.

does anyone have any idea where to start with this idea.

Comment: Why? If you don't want anyone else to read it, encryption is the only real solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is bad form. SuperUser is not a script writing service and I do not want to encourage this behavior, but what you're asking is so easy that, well... here's a little VBScript file that will get the job done:

```
Const USBFILE = "C:\Whatever.usb"    'Or whatever file name you want here
Const USB_DRIVE = "E:"    'Or whatever letter your USB drive is

Dim objShell :Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim objFS :Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")

If objFS.FileExists(USBFILE) = False Then
    objShell.Run "mountvol " & USB_DRIVE & " /d"
End If
```

Save that file as a `.vbs`

Incorporating that into an `Autorun.inf` and tweaking it for your needs is up to you.  This question is already off-topic as it is.

Comment: how can we move this topic to there. I really wanna continue this topic with you :)

Comment: I'm bad with scripting. so could you explain your lines more clearly. Like, you made USB_DRIVE but you never used it !??

Comment: It's probably better to ask on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). You'll also get better traction if you ask specific questions about how/why your particular method worked/didn't work rather than generalities. The reason this question is off-topic isn't because you're asking a scripting question. It's off-topic because you're asking for product or learning material recommendations. Those kinds of questions are better for suited to forums rather than Q&A sites like this one.

Comment: Not using USB_DRIVE was actually a typo on my part :-)  Thanks for noticing it.  I corrected my answer.  All the script does is checks for the file (line 7) and runs the `mountvol` command if it exists (line 8).  The rest of the code is just declaring variables.

Answer (score 2):

USB devices shouldn't be allowed to auto-run arbitrary code (Windows now prompts to ask if you want to execute the autorun functionality of CDs/DVDs/USB devices). So I don't think you can expect to have a USB device auto-disconnect itself in that fashion.

However, if you were able to program the USB controller chip on the USB drive, you might be able to effectively disable the device if the host machine doesn't match certain parameters. I'm not experienced in that world to say how to do that, nor do I know what sort of parameters could be checked. I'm assuming that something at this low of a level is beyond something you want to take on, so I'd say that your idea simply isn't possible via autorun based on the fact that machines do not execute that code automatically. You can configure that for machines you know and use, but I assume that's not the scope of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I've read the controller programming tools are all in chinese too